# Multiplying a textbox input value on the same textbox

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to do this right. I've achieved computing values using 3 textboxes. But what I want is when I input a value, it would automatically multiply on the value that I've assigned without the use of another textbox. Is this achievable in javascript?

Comment: Made a function called compute. It multiplies the input by .80. I don't know where to pass the result. A textbox can't have two ids right?

Comment: @BenedictJohnPayot just paste that code here and format it with Ctrl + K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its achievable, you can use jQuery for this , here is example : http://jsfiddle.net/26vmdtcj/

add the input with this code:

```
<input id="input_id" type="text">
```

add javascript :

```
$('#input_id').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 3);
});
```

and you are ready, also dont forget to add jquery with this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```